# how to fetch data in multiple div from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter .I have the one table with following column name.

```
id month day year review source
```

the table name is testimonial.there is lots of row in testimonial table.i want all testimonial details should be display in separate box.how i fetch data from database in separate box .

**I have tried:**

**// In controller**

```
class edit_content extends CI_Controller {

    function edit_content()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('editcontent_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('acl');
        $this->data = $this->editcontent_model->get_contents();
    }
}
```

**// In view**

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($this->data  as $r): ?>
        <tr>
            <tr><?php echo $r['review']; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<table>
```

**// in model**

```
class editcontent_model extends CI_Model {
    var $CI; 

    function editcontent_model(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_contents() {
        $this->db->select('review');
        $this->db->from('testimonials');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('edit_content/edit_content', $result);
    }
}
```

But this i only used for one column. and its not working i was trying to get all column details in one box. Please help me on this.

I am new on codeigniter please help me to find the solution

Comment: Can you give us a brief summary of what you have tried?

Comment: i have one table .table name is testimonials.in testimonial table there is some column name which i already given in the question.I want fetch data from testimonial table and display in different different div or box.example in one row three box contain the testimonial details(date,testimonial description,review by) and after this three box in one line etc.

Comment: I read the question. I did not ask what your question was, I asked what you have already attempted to achieve this result.

Comment: see the link https://jsfiddle.net/27j65vsL/3/..in this i only used for one column.and its not working i want all column details in one box

Comment: jsfiddle.net/27j65vsL/3

Comment: @nushrat PHP in jsfiddle does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code helps you.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, month,day,year,review,source FROM testimonials');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->id;
    echo $row->month;
    echo $row->day;
    echo $row->year;
    echo $row->review;
    echo $row->source;
}

echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
```

in above code i have give simple demo how to display data now based on your requirement and theme you can use your div for display in differnt box or row how you want. hope i will helps you.

Comment: dinesh i know that process .the main problem is i dont know how to display in one div or box in proper way

Comment: @nushart  it means are you talking about in design view  so can please tell me which theme you are using what you have did till can you please share that code

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're using two `<tr>` tags instead of a `<td>` tag.

```
//In controller 
class edit_content extends CI_Controller {

    function edit_content()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('editcontent_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('acl');
        $this->data = $this->editcontent_model->get_contents();
    }
}

 // In view
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($this->data  as $r): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r['review']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<table>

// in model
class editcontent_model extends CI_Model {
    var $CI; 

    function editcontent_model(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_contents() {
        $this->db->select('review');
        $this->db->from('testimonials');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('edit_content/edit_content', $result);
    }
}
```

### if you'd like to get all of the columns printed out, then look at the code below

```
//In controller 
class edit_content extends CI_Controller {

    function edit_content()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('editcontent_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('acl');
        $this->data = $this->editcontent_model->get_contents();
    }
}

 // In view
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($this->data  as $r): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($r as $v): ?>
            <td><?php echo $r['review']; ?></td>
            <?php endoforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<table>

// in model
class editcontent_model extends CI_Model {
    var $CI; 

    function editcontent_model(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_contents() {
        $this->db->select('review');
        $this->db->from('testimonials');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();
        $this->load->view('edit_content/edit_content', $result);
    }
}
```